# PhoneGap/Cordova calendar integration (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, phonegap-plugins, android-calendar

I'm building an Android app using PhoneGap (aka Cordova), and am having trouble getting a calendar integration to work.  **Disclaimer:** I'm a noob to both Android and PhoneGap, please bear with me.

All I'm trying to do is add an event to the user's calendar.  Following [this tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html), I've created a Plugin that attempts to launch a Calendar Intent.  The code looks like this:

```
public class CalendarPlugin extends Plugin {
public static final String NATIVE_ACTION_STRING="addToCalendar"; 
public static final String SUCCESS_PARAMETER="success"; 

@Override
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data, String callbackId) {
    if (NATIVE_ACTION_STRING.equals(action)) { 
        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        beginTime.set(2012, 6, 19, 7, 30);
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.set(2012, 6, 19, 8, 30);

        Intent calIntent = new Intent((Context) this.ctx, CalendarPlugin.class)
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "A new event")
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis());

        this.ctx.startActivity(calIntent);
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "Smashing success");
    }

return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "Didn't work bro");
}
}
```

The Javascript code to invoke this plugin is standard:

```
var CalendarPlugin = { 
    callNativeFunction: function (success, fail, resultType) { 
        if (cordova) {
            return cordova.exec( success, fail, 
                "org.myorg.appname.CalendarPlugin", 
                "addToCalendar", [resultType]);
        }
        else {
            alert("Calendar function is not available here.");
        }
    } 
};
```

The Android code is getting invoked (confirmed using a breakpoint).  But the result sent back to the Javascript code is an error:

> Unable to find explicit activity class {org.myorg.appname/org.myorg.appname.CalendarPlugin}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

There's no mention of adding to AndroidManifest.xml in the tutorial, which leads me to believe I'm missing something (also, the *CalendarPlugin* code is being invoked successfully, so how could there be an error saying the *CalendarPlugin* class could not be found?).  If indeed I need to add *CalendarPlugin* to the manifest, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial cited didn't cover intents. The intent you are sending your data to is your own CalendarPlugIn class which isn't what you want as it doesn't handle the intent.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html regarding intents.

Also if you search around SO you'll find that until ICS there wasn't even a way to add things to the Google Calendar officially without using a web service. There are ways to do it unofficially, but are subject to the whims of Google or the ODMs themselves.

Updated:

You should be able to use intents with Phonegap (via a plugin). I only added the comment to note that if you intend to have calendar integration in your app, you'll probably have to do a bit of research if you want to support the majority of Android devices. If you are interested in adding calendar events in ICS look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html

*Op's Edit*

I just needed to fix the *Intent* constructor, and this worked as expected:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
Intent calIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.INSERT", uri)
```

Comment: So do you think my approach is even feasible on ICS and above?  Is it possible to work with Intents from Phonegap plugins?

Comment: Thanks- your point about the Intent pointed me in the right direction.  (Also, I hope you don't mind, I just amended your answer for completeness.)

Comment: @dbaseman Don't mind. Just realize that its a not an officially supported intent.

Comment: Do you mean it's only officially supported in ICS and above?  I'm looking at documentation which suggests it's officially supported in some sense:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-insert

Comment: Correct. My bad. Only in ICS and above is it officially supported, per your link.

Comment: @Jitu no, but I'll be working on it in the next few weeks -- if I find anything out, I'll post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

For making it work for all android sdk version try this following code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
 intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
```

I tried its working for me.