# Phonegap Android can I add an event to Android's calendar?

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to call Android's calendar from a Phonegap app and write in that calendar.

Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhoneGap Android Calender Integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511717/phonegap-android-calender-integration)

Comment: Please check

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873997/phonegap-cordova-calendar-integration-android